# Get the jquery index of same element class within different containers

Tags: jquery, indexing

On the event "click", I would like to get the index of an element that can be in multiple container. The index position returned should be calculated relatively to its container and not to the body tag.

I wrote an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/

My problem is that when I click on the lines in the second block container, the line index returned are: 3, 4, 5 whereas I would like 0, 1, 2 to be returned.

What should I change in the jquery index() arguments to get 0, 1, 2 returned for each line in both containers?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/

```
$('.line').click(function()
{
    alert('index: '+$(this).index('.container .line'));
});

<div class="container">
<div class="header">block #1</div>
<div class="line">line #0</div>
<div class="line">line #1</div>
<div class="line">line #2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="header">block #2</div>
<div class="line">line #0 (index 3 returned instead of 0)</div>
<div class="line">line #1 (index 4 returned instead of 1)</div>
<div class="line">line #2 (index 5 returned instead of 2)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this to get the index value for elements within it's container

```
$(function()
{
    $('.line').click(function()
    {
        //alert('index: '+$(this).index('.container .line'));

        alert($(this).closest('.container').find('.line').index(this));
    });
});
```

You have to use this syntax of [$.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
.index( element )
element The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for.
​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/zUGcK/1/)

Comment: What if the line block is also inside a line-container block? Can you have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/32/ In this case, the index returned is always -1 (the element index is not found but I can't see what I'm doing wrong). I'm trying to get the index for the button container (line being the button, and line-container being the container of the button). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/22/ , this is the same fiddle as in your question. did you update this?

Comment: It works just fine, many thanks. I just understood why it couldn't find .line as .line is not a "direct" child of .container Thanks again

Comment: You are most welcome. The thing is you have to find all the considering elements(in this case elements with class `line`) in current container, then have to find the index of clicked one using `allofthem.index(this)` . Hope it makes sense.

Comment: In the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/41/ what should I modify in the find() function to get 1 and 2 as index values for line-container if the first line-container is empty but the two others are filled with a "line" element? Any idea?

Comment: You can add `1` to index value based on that condition, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/zUGcK/45/

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally found the right way to do it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zUGcK/46/ Thanks for having taken the time to answer me, best regards.

Comment: I thought you were finding the index of `.line`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just spent an hour and a half trying to hunt this down. Answer was pretty obvious, but man, that was difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Updated index with $this.

```
 $('.line').click(function()
{
    var $this=$(this);
   var indx= $this.parent('.container').find('.line').index($this);

    alert('index: '+indx);
});
```

Comment: No, `$(this).index()` looks at all the siblings so it includes `div.header` and you end up with your index off by one.